# TFS everywhere shows the every file (property) changed

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and running eclipse with tfs everywhere,
I edited only one file but in pending cahnges I see that every file was changed. (type of change for files I didn't edit is proprty).

[click here for a screen shot of the situation (it shows more than 15,000 changes!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07tjR.png)

It is impossible to navigate in this situation.

Does anyone familiar with solution?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of TFS are you using?

Did these files are included in the project?

If you make changes outside Eclipse to projects that are in your Eclipse workspace, changes will be detected automatically.

You can In the **Excluded Changes** section, choose **Detected changes**. In the **Promote Candidate Changes** dialog box, make sure only files that you want to check in are selected, and then choose **Promote**.